# PHP looping through MySQL array

Tags: php

I have the following **PHP query code**:

```
$theirTable = $dbcon->query("SELECT * FROM dogbreed");
$theirRow = $theirTable->fetch_assoc();
```

I am trying to understand the correct method for displaying all records in my chosen table in a loop. My request is done like so:

```
            <?php
                while ($fow = $theirRow){
                    echo $fow['dogtype'];
                }
            ?>
```

This code proves problematic, as it repeats the first response endlessly. So I end up getting a result like `dobermandobermandobermandobermandoberman`continously. Not sure what my problem is from a logic standpoint.

Comment: You are not fetching any more rows after the first one: `while ($fow = $theirTable->fetch_assoc()){` (and skip the original fetch).

Comment: I think you can better use foreach for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should iterate over fetch_assoc result

```
      <?php
            while ($fow = $theirTable->fetch_assoc()){
                echo $fow['dogtype'];
            }
        ?>
```

Comment: remove the semicolon at while

Comment: @hungrykoala   ... many thanks  .. semicolon removed  ..

Comment: I am having trouble identifying how your code is different from mine. yet it does not repeat the same line over again. however, this code only shows me 1 value. for some reason it does not echo the entire results of my array. I have 2 dogtypes and it is only echoing 1.

Comment: The reason it is different is because it is fetching a row during each loop, where you were assigning one row to a variable and trying to loop on that.

Comment: @JasonChen   simple ... in you you assign to$fow the value form $theirTable->fetch_assoc() just once  .. and you don't  call no more $theirTable->fetch_assoc() .. so the value remain the same  .. in mine the while loop call the $theirTable->fetch_assoc()  until  find result  .. so i repeated  fo all the rows selected ... hope is clear

Comment: I C. After I removed the `$theirRow` variable I was able to get it to work.

Comment: @JasonChen   explain better you comment  .. i don't understand

Comment: I just meant that after I deleted my `$theirRow` variable I was able to echo both values using your code. It's strange considering that `$theirRow` wasn't used when I copied your code, and yet it only allowed my PHP to echo the 1 result.

Comment: @JasonChen   ... remember that each time you call $theirTable->fetch_assoc()  you move the pointer to the next row ..